# Angular, alternative solution to setting multiple watchers to fire dynamic events - optimized observer pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, observer-pattern

So I have a factory that is set to watch URL changes, and then fire and change scope variables in controllers to keep them updated if the URL changes. The basic idea is I have a URL object I'm storing that sends information into different modules to control their state. This is so the user can copy/bookmark a URL and have a saved state, if you will.

So what I have right now is bound to every scope variable in every controller that is controlled by this. It works great, however the issue I have with this, is if I (potentially) have 90 different states in the url, that is 90 watchers, and everytime I change the url the function is fires 90 times, when most likely it only needs to fire to 1 or 2 of them.

So here is the code now -

The factory :

```
 .factory('urlWatch', function(urlFactory) {
    return {
        listenToUrl: function(scope, moduleName, stateName, bindTo) { 
            //create closure for binding a watch to specific scope on controller
            scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
                //parseState just checks if it's an acceptable state
                scope[bindTo] = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName);
            });
        }
    };

});
```

and in the controllers, I would do something like:

```
//set initial state
$scope.mod1m1 = urlFactory.parseState("module1", "mod1");
//hook onto url listener
urlWatch.listenToUrl($scope, "module1", "mod1", "mod1m1");
```

So, right now I have this in 2 different controllers, on 2 scopes each, so every time the scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess') fires, it sends out to all 4.

What am I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to optimize this so it only sends what it needs to. I can keep a "1 back" version of the url object pretty easily to check what has changed and maybe wrap this in a conditional?

Lets say I had access to what was changed for example, could I do something like this -

```
.factory('urlWatch', function(urlFactory) {
    return {
        listenToUrl: function(scope, moduleName, stateName, bindTo, whatsChanged) { 

            scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
                 if(whatsChanged == moduleName[stateName]){
                //parseState just checks if it's an acceptable state
                scope[bindTo] = urlFactory.parseState(moduleName, stateName); }
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Checking if the changed url item matches the current item (moduleName[stateName]) and if so, then fire. I am not sure if this is the best way of approaching this. I am looking for an optimized observer pattern.

What I am struggling with is how to set this up correctly, and could definitely use some input on the issue. Thank you for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your problem correctly then from my point of view, the best way is to change your urlWatcher factory to the global singleton service and respond on route change event only once inside this factory. Factory will keep current route parameters and every controller may check these parameters and setup according to them. Global service may look like:

```
app.service("routeWatcher", function (){
  var service={};

  service.watchFunction=function (event, data){
    service.currentRouteParams=data.params;
  };

  return service;
}])
```

which is used globally (services are created on demand so we need to instantiate it on start):

```
.run(function ($rootScope, routeWatcher){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',routeWatcher.watchFunction);
})
```

Then any controller that needs setup depending on route parameters may get this value from single point:

```
app.controller("test1", function ($scope, routeWatcher){
  /*I need to get my specific route params here*/
  $scope.param=routeWatcher.currentRouteParams["param"];
})
```

Here is my plunker where first view/controller uses parameter from the route http://plnkr.co/edit/NbDoCgt71xPAZgKaSxwi?p=preview